# What is the ways to distinguish str/unicode from bytes/str uniformly in python 3.x and 2.x?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, unicode, python-2.x

In python 2.x, there are strings of unicode characters called `unicode` and strings of bytes called `str` which are often being misused for textual data because it's the default. Fortunately, python 3.x solves this by defaulting to py2 `unicode` and letting the user chose the py2 `str` when working with binary data or *encoded* text. But it also renames py2 `unicode` to `str` and py2 `str` to `bytes`.

I'm aware of a number of methods to write code for both 3.x and 2.x to distinguish them but I would like to know other opinions on which methods are the best and why and possibly learn about methods I don't know, yet. I'm also aware that some ways may better fit some circumstances, so feel free to expose all of them in your answers.

This question also servers me anyone else to choose the best option but I was reminded that this is a matter of opinion.

So here are the ways known to me...

Using the type of "" and enforcing it to be the unicode type:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

if isinstance(string, type("")):
    ...
```

Catching the NameError exception and using version specific code.

Thinks that don't seem to be working...

Using `getattr()` to check for `encode()` and `decode()` methods as Python 2.x seems to use both methods for both types.

As I can't add any answer any more, here's what I'm finally going to use:

```
# Ensure compatibility with Python < 2.7 (2.7 uses bytes as an alias for str).
if 'bytes' not in vars():
    bytes = str

if isinstance(name, bytes):
    ...byte string...
else:
    ...unicode string...
```

Comment: Opinion-gathering questions are off-topic; some people also construe asking such questions as showing a lack of research, hence the downvote. (Myself, I just vote to close.)

Comment: A better question might be "I chose method 1, does it have any disadvantages compared to method 2?" Simply stating that you are aware of a number of options does not demonstrate that you actually *are* aware of the options, and such language is often used to hide a lack of research.

Comment: Fair enough, I will add known ways to the question. I just don't think closing a question like this one, upvoted by three people probably interested in the answers, is the way to help the content of stack exchange in any way. But feel free to continue racing to close the question before I can edit it.

Comment: Questions can be reopened after they are closed. There have been long discussions on *why* opinion-based questions are closed, and it's your responsibility to know what questions are off-topic *before* you ask them. If you have a problem with the definition of "off-topic", the appropriate place to address it is on meta.stackoverflow.com, but I guarantee you are not the first person to question the policy, and you will not get much sympathy there.

Comment: I can guarantee that you didn't get my sympathy by originally voting to close without a comment. I'm always trying to comment even when downvoting, unless the reason is clear from previous comments from others.

Comment: You're going to have to allow people time to *type* comments after down voting; it's hardly unreasonable to allow a minute or two for typing.

Comment: Not if they're not giving me time before voting to close. Plus there's still the possibility to comment *before* taking action.

Comment: I just realized I have the privilege of closing as well, so let's make it quicker.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [six](http://pythonhosted.org/six/), which was designed to solve this and other 2-to-3 migration problems.

I'd still suggest the `from __future import unicode_literals` statement you mentioned, just to make sure the strings from your own source are handled consistently, but for everything else, you might find the [string-related constants in six](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#constants) useful:

- `six.text_type` evaluates to `str` in 3 and `unicode` in 2.
- `six.binary_type` evaluates to `bytes` in 3 and `str` in 2.
- `six.string_types` can be useful for `isinstance` checks and evaluates to `str` in 3 and `basestring` in 2.

Comment: Ah, this looks like the way to go... but the not so nice thing is that it is outside the standard library.

Comment: True, although it also is built so you can just package it with your code if necessary; just put `six.py` in your application along with your other modules. [Here is an example](https://github.com/myersjustinc/wtnv-metadata) of a project where I do just that.

Comment: Yep, I would do the same if using more than just the test/binary types but I found out I can support older python versions with what I described in the question.